# Laravel : How to update cache when I copy whole project folder from local to cloud server?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel `5.3`.

On my local windows PC , the database name is `test` in `.env` file ,
I copy the whole project folder to cloud server , the database name is `laravel` in `.env` file ,

then I run `php artisan migrate`，there is an error that says `Unknown database 'test'`,as follow:

```
  [PDOException]                                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'test'
```

I don't create database `test` and not use it,I use database `laravel`.
Is that caused by cache?

`database.php` is like this:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

**edit:**

.env on cloud server

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:fzg/000000000000000001qfE0=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

.env on local PC

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:fzg/000000000000000001qfE0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Those settings don't get cached.  Did you happen to hardcode that database name inside your database.php file?

Comment: @user3158900 see my edit, I add the relevent content of  `database.php`